# Rails SCORM LMS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scorm

Are there any LMS (hosting SCORM) Rails gems or apps written in Ruby on Rails?
I would be using Articulate to create the SCORM.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's Canvas LMS. It appears to be under very active development, with the most recent update to master happening yesterday:

https://github.com/instructure/canvas-lms/wiki

http://guides.instructure.com/m/4214/l/41907

I don't have any personal experience with it so I can't comment on its quality.

Comment: SCORM actually only has partial support through Canvas LMS.

Comment: I think he was looking for a gem that would implement the LMS portion of a SCORM engine for him. not only is Canvas a full blown lms, their SCORM support isn't particularly good.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SCORMCloud to serve the SCORM content from Rails.

There's a github repo that implements some of the API:

https://github.com/aeseducation/scorm-cloud

Just be careful of running rake test there..... it tries to delete all of your courses (not good if its pointed at a prod environment).

My company builds integs for SCORMCloud, our Bright service uses a rails back end a fork of the AES lib (we are planning on recommitting this back onto github soon).

Answer (score 1):

Another option worth exploring will be Fedena. More information about it can be found at http://www.projectfedena.org/ or https://github.com/projectfedena/fedena. I am not sure how it stacks up agains Canvas LMS. But I would love to know about it if someone over here can share.

tags - [ror](/questions/tagged/ror) [scorm](/questions/tagged/scorm) [lms](/questions/tagged/lms)